# At forms, "Required: true" is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I'm making a Rails app but I'm having this issue

In my form, I'm trying to make required some fields but it is not working.

```
<%= f.input :name, required: true, label: false, placeholder: "Name", input_html: {class: "form-control"} %>
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

If you place `required: true` in the input you should see the field has the "required" class and `required="required"` attribute.

If you're not seeing a `required` attribute, then check your `simple_form` initializer (`config/initializers/simple_form.rb`) and ensure that browser validations are on:

```
config.browser_validations = true
```

I believe it's also possible to override the required attribute through the `input_html` hash, for a single field. For example:

```
<%= f.input :name, label: false, placeholder: "Name", input_html: { class: "form-control", required: true } %>
```

Personally, I don't like browser validations. They feel clunky to me. If you're interested in better client-side validations, then check out the [judge gem](https://github.com/joecorcoran/judge) and it's [simple_form adapter](https://github.com/joecorcoran/judge-simple_form).

Comment: I had this issue and it was not solved by only doing the above. However, updating simple_form with the above did fix my issue (specifically with the country_select gem). Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 5):

add this to the f.input `input_html: { required: true }`

after setting `config.browser_validations = true`

`Reset rails server`. <-- this took me awhile to realize since config are run once every time you start the server

Answer (score 4):

Be careful, it is `required: true` NOT `require: true`